# Primefaces keyboard language support

Tags: primefaces, keyboard

I want to integrate the Primefaces `< p:keyboard >` into my application, but i need to load different layouts based on the user locale.

Now, the keyboard component have an atrtibute called `lang` that I expected that will do exactly what I need, but it seems that it's not for this purpose from component documentation: `"Code describing the language used in the generated markup for this component"`.

My next approach was to create a `layout="custom"` and provide the appropiate `layoutTemplate` based on the user language. For example, if the language is de, i added the appropriate german letters, but in case of buttons they still remain in English. For example:

```
<p:keyboard id="testDe" layout="custom" layoutTemplate="1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-ß-space-close"</p:keyboard>
```

The `close` word from `layoutTemplate` it's a predefined keyword that will generate a close button for the keyboard. 
My question is: is there a way I can use localization for the keyboard? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use comma(,) comma mean new line

this

```
<p:keyboard id="testDe" layout="custom" layoutTemplate="1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0-ß-space-close"</p:keyboard>
```

to

```
<p:keyboard layout="custom" layoutTemplate="123,456,789,0ßspace,close"/>
```

[for example turkish](http://kod5.org/primefaces-keyboard-bilesenini-ozellestirme/)

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, especially about the text of the buttons. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I might have another question related to this, do you have any idea how to add the "Enter" button on the keyboard? the primefaces examples/documentation for this component is very thin

Answer (score 0):

I used the Turkish example above, but without using the layoutTemplate. I just used the tags:

```
keypadOnly = "true"
backspaceLabel = "Voltar"
closeLabel = "Fechar"
clearLabel = "Limpar"
```

for my language (pt_BR). Thank you Ilkay GÜNEL. http://kod5.org/primefaces-keyboard-bilesenini-ozellestirme/